# Leaflet MarkerCluster removeOutsideVisibleBounds not working

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, ngx-leaflet

I have a Leaflet map that uses the [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin.

The clusters plot properly on the map but I am noticing that the clusters that are outside the view are still rendering even though I have the `removeOutsideVisibleBounds` option set to `true`.

The way I can tell is if I pan the map by pressing and holding the mouse button, all of the clusters are still visible as I pan.

The configuration for the cluster group is below:

```js
let myCluster = L.markerClusterGroup({ spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false, removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true });
```

What else am I missing to ensure that the clusters that are outside of the view are removed?

The project is in Angular 5 using ngx-leaflet.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just missed this part of the `removeOutsideVisibleBounds` option description (emphasis mine):

> removeOutsideVisibleBounds: Clusters and markers **too far** from the viewport are removed from the map for performance.

What this "too far" means is that it still keeps markers and clusters within a "buffer" area of 1 viewport size in each direction; except for mobile, where the buffer area is 0, in order to be lighter on device memory.

Therefore on desktop browsers, you have to pan the map by more than 1 map viewport size before you see missing markers and clusters, that re-appear only when you stop panning (release the mouse).

If you inspect the [source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/v1.3.0/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L1070-L1079):

> Gets the maps visible bounds expanded in each direction by the size of the screen (so the user cannot see an area we do not cover in one pan)

Comment: What is 1 viewport size?  Is that the total size of the current map?

Comment: That is the size of your map **container**, i.e. typically your `<div id="map">`