# Leaflet on mobile - json marker with layer.setIcon disappear outside map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, marker, leaflet.markercluster

I have a map with different levels. Each level takes information from a json file and generates the icons with the layer.setIcon method.
By dragging the map, the icons disappear when are outside the displayed area.
Why?

[image]

EDIT:
Okay, I think I see the problem here:
[Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport)
Without this extension, rendering works... why?

Comment: This the default behaviour on leaflet, performance optimization

Comment: Without seeing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behaviour of Leaflet.markercluster plugin, especially visible on mobile.

More specifically, it has a `removeOutsideVisibleBounds` option that is enabled by default:

> removeOutsideVisibleBounds: Clusters and markers too far from the viewport are removed from the map for performance.

On mobile, anything outside the current map viewport is removed, and re-appears when panning stops. But this means that *during* pan, you may miss some markers.

See also [Leaflet MarkerCluster removeOutsideVisibleBounds not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418715/leaflet-markercluster-removeoutsidevisiblebounds-not-working/50420866?r=SearchResults#50420866)

Unfortunately, there is no API to customize this behaviour, other than disabling it by passing the option to `false`:

```js
const mcg = L.markerClusterGroup({
    removeOutsideVisibleBounds: false // Disable default behaviour
}).addTo(map);
```

Demo on mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/4weocd0q/1/embedded/#Result

Comment: Unfortunately even with the parameter set to `false` the problem remains.

Comment: For me the problem is the extension MarkerCluster.LayerSupport.

Comment: Probably worth making it a separate question, then. With an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make sure the problem is reproducible with details provided in the question.